# How to run the Windows 7 On-Screen Keyboard in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, on-screen-keyboard

I'm searching for an On-Screen Keyboard application for Windows XP that can be resized.

It must also save the new size of the window so that the next time it starts, it will open to  the previous size.

The application that comes with Windows 7 is a perfect match, but unfortunately it must run on Windows XP.

Can I run it on Windows XP? If not, any other recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Click-N-Type**](http://www.lakefolks.org/cnt/) is resizable and will remember the previous size from the last run. The only thing I noticed is a short hang when closing the application, likely because of all the settings it is saving for the next run. The application still works great though.

[image]

Click-N-Type is freeware.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go: http://www.winmatrix.com/forums/index.php?/topic/21199-tablet-pc-input-panel-for-xp-pro-home-mce-and-original-windows-7-mat/

Comment: welcome to Super User! links by themselves don't make very good answers here.  we prefer to see at least a summary of the information at the link.  it's good to include links to backup your answer, but you should at least give us some idea of what the link contains.

Comment: -1 you have to register to see this link, and even then it might not be active any more.